# where to find folder on app engine console

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a folder with some static content, say images. I deploy to app engine and sure enough everything is working fine when I use the app as a user. But then when I go to app engine console, there is no way to go view the content of my folder. I run through all of the submenus of `Main, Data, Administration, Billing`. I suppose there has to be a way to access my folder. For deployment, I place the folder in `war` as in `war/myitems`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to view uploaded App Engine files.

Comment: I replace the content of a folder by changing the name of the image files therein. After deploying, app engine cannot find the files under their new names. But somehow the files still exist under their old names. The problem is I was able to check because I remember one of the old names and checked directly through the browser. But my app stops working properly because each call for the new names keep returning 404. Do you how to fix that problem? It's been about 7hrs now since the upload.